# Magento 2 Category Position wise product not display

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have trouble in Magento 2 default setting. They have not provided by product position wise list in category page if "Is Anchor" is set to Yes.
If  "Is Anchor" is set to No then list works perfect by position wise.